# Initializing vector with data not working - push_back() does work

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, initializer-list

I am trying to create a vector of typedefs. Whenever I try to initialize a vector with one of these typedefs, it gives a `no instance of constructor` error.

The typedef is defined as follows:

```
typedef palam::geometry::Pt2<uint16_t> CPoints;
```

and I am trying to initialize a vector like this:

```
CPoints point1(10, 15);
CPoints point2(15, 20);
std::vector<CPoints> points(point1, point2);
```

but that does not work. I am able to get around this issue by initializing the vector with a `NULL` value and then using the `push_back()` function, like this

```
CPoints point1(10, 15);
CPoints point2(15, 20);
std::vector<CPoints> points(NULL);
points.push_back(point1);
points.push_back(point2);
```

This work around seems a bit messy, and I am sure there must be a better way to go about this. Does anyone know why I am unable to directly initialize the vector using the typedefs?

Comment: `std::vector<CPoints> points(point1, point2);` This doesn't do what you think. Take a look on the documentation.

Comment: `std::vector<CPoints> points(NULL);` --  Given that `NULL` is 0, that `NULL` does absolutely nothing.  Just declaring the `vector` would have been enough.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie leaving the parameters completely empty makes it so the `push_back()` function does not work. It gives an `expression must have a class type` error.

Comment: @BrentMB So you did this: `std::vector<CPoints> points();`?  Well, you've discovered the "most vexing parse" issue.  That is a declaration of a function called `points` that takes no arguments, and returns a `std::vector<CPoints>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Interesting, I have not heard of that ambiguity before. I will look into that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet:

```
std::vector<CPoints> points(point1, point2);
```

calls the `vector` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking 2 arguments. If you want to initialize a `vector` with multiple elements, use `{}`, like this:

```
std::vector<CPoints> points {point1, point2};
```

This calls overload number 9, which takes an initializer list.

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question perfectly.

Comment: @BrentMB If this answers your question, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this record

```
std::vector<CPoints> points = { point1, point2 };
```

Or this

```
std::vector<CPoints> points { point1, point2 };
```

or this

```
std::vector<CPoints> points( { point1, point2 } );
```

That is use an initializer list if you want to supply several objects simultaneously to a vector.

Otherwise the compiler tries to apply one of these constructors

```
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
template <class InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

that are invalid for the specified arguments in the declaration

```
std::vector<CPoints> points(point1, point2);
```